# flutter: i cant resize flutter_cached_pdfview widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Im fairly new to Flutter. So im basically trying to show PDF from a URL inside `showModalBottomSheet`. im using `flutter_cached_pdfview` package to show PDF. `showModalBottomSheet` takes roughly 2/3 of the screen.

Iv been able to show the PDF but the problem i have is resizing the PDF to fit within `showModalBottomSheet`. Its basically overflowing hence, the right most part of the PDF is being cut off.

an excerpt of the PDF and its parent.

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  builder: (context) => Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topRight: Radius.circular(25),
          topLeft: Radius.circular(25)),
    ),
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minWidth: 50,
            maxWidth: mediaQuery.size.width - 16,
            minHeight: 100,
            maxHeight: mediaQuery.size.height - 16,
          ),
          color: const Color(0xFFE4E9EC),
          child: const PDF().cachedFromUrl(.....)
        )
      ]
    )
  )
)
```

any ideas/suggestion will be helpful. thanks

Comment: please show me a design u try to make like it and I will give u a code 
I am the developer of flutter_cached_pdfview
https://github.com/AbdOoSaed/flutter_cached_pdfview